# passing python variable in echo command

Tags: python, string, shell, echo, paramiko

I am new to python as well as shell. I am trying to send this command, (parse "Varying sentence") to a server.

```
('echo "(parse \\"trees are tall\\")" |nc localhost xxxxx')
```

I tried the following:

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.connect('server', username='wefw', password='fwf')

for line in json_text:
    line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    json_content = json.loads(line)
body = ''
try:
    body = json_content['id']['body']
    body_encoded = body.encode('utf-8')  
    stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('echo "(parse \\"${body_encoded}\\"})" |nc localhost xxxxx')
```

The sentences vary. i cannot hard code the sentence in parse command. so i tried passing the variable "body_encoded" like this:

```
  ('echo "(parse \\"${body_encoded}\\")" |nc localhost xxxxx')
```

But something is wrong here. How can i pass variable, "body_encoded" that has a string value?

```
  exec_command('echo "(parse \\"varying sentence\\")"')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string interpolation:

```
ssh_client.exec_command('echo "(parse \\"%s\\")" |nc localhost xxxxx' % body)
```

Comment: This seems to be more appropriate answer. I tried it. But i could not get that working. The body is not sent. Hard coding only works for me. :-(. Any way to debug?

Comment: Try constructing the string and printing it _before_ you call `exec_command` to verify that the interpolation is working. If it isn't, try printing `body` to verify that it contains what you expect.

Comment: yeah i checked printing the "body"  after exec_command. It has the sentence. i also printed str(body) before exec_command. It also works.!!

Comment: Then you could try doing `echo "(parse \\"%s\\"})" > somefile.txt` and check if the file contains the expected string. If it does, the problem is with whatever is on the other end of `nc`.

Comment: In any case, seeing the contents of that file will help.

Comment: yeah you were obviously right, I checked the contents of the file. In  (parse \\"%s\\"}).  There is an extra curly brace. (see your answer post)I did not notice that. Now it works!!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

Try passing a raw string like that:
`(r'echo "(parse \"trees are tall\")" |nc localhost xxxxx')`
i.e. instead using escape characters add an 'r' just before your string. Maybe that would help.

Comment: No the sentences vary. I need to send a variable, that holds the sentence.